# Should I double up grounding wires under lugs in panel or pigtail them?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding, code-compliance

I have a Square D Homeline panel.  I recently had to open it to replace a breaker, and I noticed that the neutral bar has very few, if any, free lugs/screws under which to attach neutrals and grounds.  In fact, I noticed a number of doubled-up wires.  I believe that this box allows two grounding wires under a single lug.  I know that two neutrals are *not* allowed.

I have to add several breakers (box will then be full) and would like to to tidy it a little when I do so.  I also want to fix any cases if they exist where the previous homeowner put two neutrals under a single lug.  Assuming that I do not have enough free lugs:

**Is it better to pigtail several grounds together and then attach to a single lug, or is it better to attach two grounds under a single lug?**

I believe both are valid by code, but I am interested to get insight if there is a preferred option.  Depending on exactly how much space there is, I would like to pigtail 4 grounds together and have them share a single lug.  Doing this would free up more lugs than simply doubling grounds.  Any good reason not to do that?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the inside of your panel?

Comment: You r panel may have space for an additional grounding bar, allowing you to move all the grounds over & free up space on the existing neutral bar.

Comment: Yeah, your panel should definitely have room for at least one accessory grounding bar (PKxGTA/GTAL) if not more

Comment: I'll try to remember to take a photo when I next open it up, @Jack

Comment: An additional grounding bar - this is why I post on this forum, as that option wouldn't have been on my radar otherwise.  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have to add several breakers (box will then be full) and would like to to tidy it a little when I do so.

All hot **and neutral** wires should be long enough to reach any breaker space in the panel.  This excess length can be managed neatly, e.g. by "overshoot and come back".  Beware the novice's impulse to cut all wires short so they only reach where they are going now.  That's how you get a panel full of wire nuts!

> I also want to fix any cases if they exist where the previous homeowner put two neutrals under a single lug. Assuming that I do not have enough free lugs:

> Is it better to pigtail several grounds together and then attach to a single lug, or is it better to attach two grounds under a single lug?
>
> I believe both are valid by code,

**Pigtailing:** for grounds yes, for neutrals no.

**2 or 3 grounds under a single lug:** Decided by UL based on their testing. The approved action will be stated on the panel labeling.  Instructions and labeling are also approved by UL. You must follow them, NEC 110.3(B).

On Square D, expect 3 per lug for (built-in) bars.

**1 neutral + any other wire under a single modern lug:**: NEVER.  NEC requires 1 solo neutral per lug.  UL cannot override that.

Generally, every panel manufacturer will give you *just* enough neutral spaces so the panel can be full of 120V circuits and have 1 neutral per lug + the grounds max-packed per panel labeling.

However, if you don't want to fool around with that nonsense, **feel free to get accessory ground bars**.  Grounds can be moved to an accessory ground bar.  Neutrals cannot (since they carry current normally).

Note that accessory ground bars may have different rules.  I've seen "3 on the neutral bars, 2 on the accessory bars".

Comment: Choosing this as answer - Ecnerwal's also answers my question equally well, though this one has a little bit of extra information as well.

Comment: No skin off my nose. ;^)

Comment: "Neutrals cannot (since they carry current normally)" - So when the neutral bar is full, what to do?

Comment: @JTP #1 pack the grounds as tight as is allowed.  #2 get a separate ground bar and move the grounds to it.  #3 get rid of illegal double-stuff breakers which are not allowed in those spaces (they should not have fit, but someone cheated). #4 get rid of the panel, it doesn't comply with UL rules and was never UL listed in the first place.  UL requires there be enough neutrals and grounds.

Comment: Thanks. Great. For my work, wiring the basement, I had an electrician install a sub-panel, and my wiring there is beautiful. The main panel, since the builder's electrician did this? Half the ground/neutral bar connections are doubled up. All I wanted to do was remove a 50A going to stove, and replace with 2 30A, as new one is seperate. Can of worms now.

Comment: @JTP Landing neutral and ground for 1 circuit on the same lug is very bad news, and I would complain to your AHJ about them passing that.  If the wires lose contact with the bar (happens all the time) *but retain contact with each other*, it will electrify every ground in the circuit!  So I would remove them mercilessly (main breaker off of course)... either add an accessory ground bar or tight-pack the grounds at labeled maximums and then 1 neutral per screw.

Comment: House is 25 years old. The inspector is long gone. The breaker I am adding will have its own connection, but I’m not happy I’m discovering this now. I appreciate all the advice.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I just looked again. Left bar has 20 connections (screws to hold wire down), Right bar has 20. There are spaces for 40 breakers. This means a full box would have every wire doubled up. With no half-heights. Might this have been code long ago?  I had a subpanel added. It has space for 20 breakers, and both bars have 20 ground/ 20 neutral slots, each.

Comment: @JTP maybe it predates grounding. In which case, accessory ground bar.  No such thing as an accessory neutral bar.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you can put multiple grounds in a hole (and how many) should be detailed on your panel label, along with the correct torque for the screws in each case.

A separate grounding bar (or bars) is, indeed, the ultimate solution, and quite simple in most cases with the proper kit for your panel. The mounting holes are usually already there.

If **correctly connected**, there's no functional difference if you would rather pigtail grounds, other than affecting more circuits if you need to disconnect them for maintenance - which is rare to the point of not worth worrying about for most homes. On the other hand, many homeowners are not great with wirenuts - but many also aren't great about using torque drivers on breaker, ground, and neutral bar screws, either. Be one of the few and it will be fine either way.

Answer (score 0):

A non-pro perspective:

Pigtail using wirenuts:  No!

- Maintenance requires disassembly of all of them
- Repeated maintenance, however unlikely, may result in broken wires requiring still more pigtails
- During maintenance, you end up with a bunch of loose springy uninsulated wires ready to poke you in the eye or to help your body find a connection to something hot.

Pigtail using 5-lever Wagos or similar: Ok, if you have them and want to get the job done. You can upgrade to a proper bus later.

- Mostly overcomes all the above objections.  Easy to maintain and disconnection of one ground keeps all the others anchored together and less likely to bounce around.
- Looks a little like a poor-man's ground bus because it's not anchored to the box.   But in reality I think a ground bus costs less than a box of Wagos so "poor man's" might be the wrong term.  I would choose this only if I already had them.